# Using sys.path.append on windows for C:\... in IDLE

Tags: python, windows, python-3.7

If I want to import a module saved in an address

> C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\MyFile\MyModules

What should I do?

I tried

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C;/Users/someone/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/MyFiles/MyModules/')
import hello
```

But then it shows the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    import hello
  File "C:/Users/someone/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/MyFiles\hello.py", line 1
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know that I can move the file hello.py to the folder site-packages and then no need to use sys.path.append and it works fine. But I want to learn how to use sys.path.append and use files even if they are on other folders or drives etc. Just to be sure that there is no problem inside of hello.py, here is the result when I move it in site-package folder.

```
>>> import hello
>>> hello.world()
Hello, world!
>>>
```

Comment: Looks like the error is in `hello.py`

Comment: @Rakesh Can you explain more? I asked import hello when I moved it to site-package folder and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the semicolon! I don't have the former files since many things have changed on my computer. But tonight that I was reading this post again I tried the following.

Before starting, I'm using Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10 (64 bit).

I made a python file saved by the name "Hello.py" in the directory "F:\" with the following code inside:

```
def Hello():
    print("Hello, you imported me as a module from another folder successfully.")
# The end of the file.
```

Then I made another python file saved by the name "Python_20191217_importing.py" in the directory "E:\Python37\Python files\" with the following code inside:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('f:/')
import Hello
```

After running it I got the following with no error.

[image]
[image]

But then when I looked at my question here more carefully, I noticed the ";" instead of ":" after the drive name! So to be the same, I changed the ":" in my current file to ";".

```
import sys
sys.path.append('f;/')
import Hello
```

And now I'm getting an error.

[image]

I also checked more ways of typing the directory which I'm not going to upload screenshots for those. Capitalizing f (typing F) doesn't change the result, so it is not related to that. You can keep using `\` and not using `/`, but then you should not type `\` at the end so here we could use `sys.path.append('f:')` and it will work fine. Or for example if the path is "E:\some folder\" then you should type `E:\some folder` (don't type `\` at the end). Otherwise you will get the following error.

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```